# Mailing List Activity Report

Tags: civimail, civireport

I wonder if there's a way to get a report on a mailing list's subscription activity, showing signups and unsubscriptions.  I don't see this option on the activity report and none of the Mailing report templates come close.  I know that the information is available by looking at contact records.

Answer (score 1):

Its not available by default by you install one of the below extension to have these feature availaible

[Mailing Subscriptions Report](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mailingsubscriptions)

[Group Growth](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/groupgrowth)

[Subscription History](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/subscriptionhistory)

Thanks

Pradeep